# HTML5 Video Player Active Title

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-video-player-with-playlist-multiple-skins/1382684
Recently I purchased this player and I want to add title means I want to make always active.How can I do it?

Comment: CAN YOU EXPLAIN BRIEFLY WHAT YOU NEED?

Comment: @AshirvadSingh dunno worry about this.I solve my problem long month ago